# Excel VBA function for concatenation not returning valid cell results (but debug.print shows the correct string)

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation

Inexperienced Stackoverflow user, please feel free to point me to a different forum or subforum if needed.

I created the following VBA (then also looked at other code samples online, which all seem to follow the same logic). I test in the debug window and see exactly the result (multi-line string) I expect. However, when I type the formula in a worksheet cell, I get a #Value error.

- The function is spelled correctly (I actually select it in Excel from the formula auto-complete)
- Excel x64 v2108, local install on Win10 x64

Any ideas why this isn't populating back into the cell with the formula?

```
Function ConcatCells()
    
    'just to be safe, clear the string
    ConcatCells = ""
    
    'Loop and add each cell text with a line break
    For Each cell In Selection
        ConcatCells = ConcatCells & Chr(13) & cell.Text
    Next
    
    'remove the leading line break
    ConcatCells = Right(ConcatCells, Len(ConcatCells) - 1)
    
    'is the string actually being created correctly? Yes
    Debug.Print ConcatCells
    
End Function
```

Comment: Are you recreating `TEXTJOIN`? The issue here is that `Selection` won't work in a user-defined function called from a worksheet. My guess is that you want a parameter: `Function ConcatCells(ByVal rng As Range)` and use `rng` instead of `Selection`. But this still seems to be recreating `TEXTJOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Selection As Range` as parameter into your function:  `Function ConcatCells(Selection As Range)`

After this, your function will return a value like this: `OneTwoThreeFourFive`

When you copy this cell and paste as value,

and after hitting `F2` and `Enter`, you will have a view like this:

[image]